# Producing curved lines connecting AVMs

Tags: diagrams, linguistics, avm

I'd like to have curved lines connecting AVMs and I currently have the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}

\begin{document}

\begin{avm}
\[ subj & \!{a}{\[ pred & \rm `pro'\\
num & sg \\
pers & 1 \]} \\
pred & \rm `want\q<\avmd{aa}, \avmd{bb}\ \q>' \\
xcomp & \!{b}{\[ pred & \rm `go\q<\avmd{aaaa}\q>' \\ subj & \avmb{aaa} \]} \]
\end{avm} 
\nodecurve[r]{a}[t]{aa}{.4in} 
\nodecurve[b]{aa}[t]{aaaa}{.2in} 
\nodecurve[r]{aaa}[b]{aaaa}{.15in} 
\nodecurve[r]{bb}[r]{b}{.5in}[.5in]

\end{document}
```

The main problem with what I have now is that it does not make curved lines. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqbqS.png when I compile this, which clearly features curved lines. Do you get something else? The only change I made was to substitute `langsci-avm` for `avm` in the preamble, because `avm.sty` seems to have been renamed `langsci-avm.sty`.

Comment: @cfr No, `avm` is not on CTAN, and `langsci-avm` is a (possibly different) copy of it.  And I get  slightly different output than yours with `avm.sty`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvrH2.png

Comment: @user1775726 Are you compiling this with `latex+dvips` (not `pfdlatex`)?  You need to be able to use `tree-dvips`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Curious. I `diff`ed `avm.sty` from TL2017 against `langsci-avm.sty` from TL2018 and it found no difference. However `langsci-avm.sty` in TL2019 is different.

Comment: You should provide a link to `avm.sty` if it is a non-standard file.

Comment: @cfr The `langsci` prefix is for the Language Science Press. They're somewhat notorious for redistributing their own versions of package without renaming (not necessarily with changes). Maybe the prefix is a sign of their finally figuring out this is a bad idea.

Comment: @AlanMunn You can always hope. But it does make it even more important the OP should include a link.

Comment: langsci-avm is an independent complete rewrite:
https://userblogs.fu-berlin.de/langsci-press/2020/04/20/writing-avms-easily-in-latex-the-new-langsci-avm-package/